# Remove old Vim-config files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, plugins

I did some experimenting with plugins and settings in the `.vim` directory and the `.vimrc` file. It broke my whole vim installation so I uninstalled it and removed all the configuration files.

After that I installed vim again but every time I start up my new installation of vim the following error messages comes from my `.vimrc` in `.vim`, even though I have removed it altogether. I've checked for hidden files with `Ctrl-H` and there was a `.vimrc.swp` which I removed as well, with no result.

```
Error detected while processing /home/myusername/.vimrc:
line    6: 
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin
line   11:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
line   16:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
line   18:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'L9'
line   20:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
line   22:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
line   25:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
line   28:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}
line   31:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#end

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So how do I remove whatever is causing these messages? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a programming question

Comment: Well, its about Vim. Vim is an text editor often used to program on and Im trying to get Vim setup for me to program stuff on.

Comment: So, it is a question about some tooling. Still doesn't make it a programming question. The point is: when people tell you that your stuff is **off-topic** the implicit hint there is: maybe there are **better** places to ask your questions. Where your chances of helpful answers are better than here!

Comment: Alright, I get your points. Ill look elsewhere

Comment: I'll just leave these here http://unix.stackexchange.com/ & http://superuser.com/...

Comment: [Vi and Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) is the site you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Run `:scriptnames` once vim starts.  This will show all files that vim has sourced since starting up.   I suspect you have a `~/.vimrc` that you haven't removed.

Edit:  Actually there *is* a file you haven't removed, and it says the filename right there at the top of the errors you posted.